# div elements go to each other

Tags: html, css

I made a div box elements that contains info about building processes in my game. All works fine but I have a design issue; the three div elements go to each other, how can I get them in line, and at the bottom of the page so that they not overlap each other?

I add my full div css and part of html in the snippet below;  I tried to add `display: inline;` but it won't do the trick.

Am I doing something wrong here?
As i tried all other posts what is similar to this nothing worked, so this question is not answered or duplicated.

```css
/* Overwiev bottom */

.content-box-s {
  margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 222px;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: -140px;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
}

.content-box-s:hover {
  margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
  width: 222px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content-box-s .header {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/b9de2f5b06c823d628d22c4067ee35.gif") no-repeat;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.content-box-s .content {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/bd764e9b39a1a48ad708039fda1bde.gif") repeat-y;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.content-box-s p {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.content-box-s .footer {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/174d5c09f617701fcaf1664a414869.gif") no-repeat;
  height: 21px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

div.content-box-s .header h3 {
  color: #6f9fc8;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 222px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contentbox {
  margin: 0 3px 0 2px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
#buttonz .contentbox .header,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header,
.contentbox .footer,
.contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  background-image: url("../images/Build_tmp/191d6af9367f608bbee2743866c489.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 -1px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header,
.contentbox .header {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-right {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-left {
  background-position: 0 -33px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-right {
  background-position: 100% -66px;
  left: auto;
  right: -2px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .content,
.contentbox .content {
  border-left: 5px double #000;
  border-right: 5px double #000;
  background: #0d1014;
  margin: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer,
.contentbox .footer {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
  height: 21px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 7px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-left {
  background-position: 0 -125px;
  left: -8px;
  right: auto;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  background-position: 100% -150px;
  left: auto;
  right: -8px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-faster-img {
  background-position: -25px -75px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster:hover .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -25px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -75px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content {
  min-height: 46px;
  height: auto!important;
  height: 46px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 177px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:link,
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:visited,
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:active {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-touch #inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction.active {
  background: #171d23;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #171d23), color-stop(100%, #101419));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#171d23', endColorstr='#101419', GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid #171d23;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.queue {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .transport_ecke {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ae6b67d617f5b4a9ad508219ca02b8.png");
  margin: 0 0 -18px 0;
  padding: 1px 5px 2px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  top: -16px;
  width: 35px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 162px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster-img,
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/f67f646a967bc6e4f54dcfcc2c3f2b.png") -25px 0 no-repeat;
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 1px 7px 0 7px;
  width: 25px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .order_dm {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-faster-img {
  background-position: -25px -50px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost,
#inhalt .content-box-s .buy_dm {
  color: #848484;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost .oldPrice {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-style: italic;
}

img.queuePic {
  border: 1px solid #141e26;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a:hover img.queuePic {
  border-color: #e7ae46;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 43px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first div {
  position: relative;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .desc {
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 130px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timer {
  color: #fff;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .ausbau {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .level {
  color: #a26d00;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll {
  padding: 5px 0 0 12px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll .shipAllCountdown,
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip .shipCountdown {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction tr.queue td {
  color: #848484;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .queue_link {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 32px;
}

#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:link,
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:visited,
.no-touch #box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:hover,
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:active {
  background: transparent none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}

#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -moz-opacity: .6;
  -khtml-opacity: .6;
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%
}

table.construction #Countdown,
table.construction #researchCountdown,
table.construction .shipCountdown {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#stationbuilding .construction a,
#stationbuilding .construction a:active {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/0349d693b02c1927643248e4167cf8.gif") no-repeat;
  color: #ff9600;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.no-touch #stationbuilding .construction a:hover,
#stationbuilding .construction a.active {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}

.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a:hover,
#resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active,
#resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link,
#resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active,
.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
#resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ce2e012805bae16d3bc0967600eb58.gif") no-repeat;
  color: #ff9600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}

.dark_highlight {
  background: #181e25 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1030px repeat-x;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2d3743), color-stop(100%, #181e25));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: #28323e #222b34 #232a34 #222b34;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

.dark_highlight:hover {
  background: #2d3743 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1080px repeat-x;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #181e25), color-stop(100%, #2d3743));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: #232b34 #232b34 #29323d #232b34;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
}

#planet1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 679px;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info span {
  color: #27db7d;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info2 {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.planet2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.planet2 .img_img {
  width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
}

.planet2:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
}

.planet2 .img_description {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="inhalt">
  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Buildings</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="idle">
              <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There is no buildings done at the moment. Click here to get to your buildings page." href="../game/game.php?page=buildings">
    You are not building anything at the moment.
   </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>



  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Research</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="construction active">

          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Computer Technology</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="first" rowspan="3">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="cancel_tech">
                <button type="submit" class="del" title="Cancel expansion of Computer Technology To Level (22)">
     <div>
                            <a >
                                <img class="queuePic" width="40" height="40" src="./styles/theme/gow/gebaeude/108.gif" alt="Computer Technology">
                            </a>
       <a>
                                <img src="../game/styles/images/del_build.jpg" height="15" width="15" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
     </button>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="desc ausbau">Improve to Level<span class="level"> (22)</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc">Duration:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc timer">
              <span id="Countdown" class="countdown2" secs="15461"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td colspan="2">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="queuetype" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="fast_tech">
                <button type="submit" class="build_submit dark_highlight onlist tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Build instantly with Antimatter.<br> Price : 858 AM" style="float: right; line-height: 18px; margin-right: 13px;">
       <a class="build-faster" >
                            <div class="build-faster-img" alt="Halve time"></div>
                            <span class="build-txt">Instant build.</span>
                            <span class="dm_cost overmark">858 AM</span>
                            <span class="order_dm">Purchase with AM.</span>
       </a>
      </button>
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>



  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Hangar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="construction active">

          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Solar Satellite</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="first" rowspan="3">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="cancel_hangar">
                <button type="submit" class="del" title="Cancel building. Solar Satellite">
     <div>
                            <a>
                                <img class="queuePic" width="40" height="40" src="./styles/theme/gow/gebaeude/212.gif" alt="Computer Technology">
                            </a>
       <a>
                                <img src="../game/styles/images/del_build.jpg" height="15" width="15" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
     </button>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="desc ausbau">Units to build<span class="level"> (995920)</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc">Duration:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc timer">
              <span id="Countdown" class="countdown2" secs="4881.9607843137"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td colspan="2">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="modo" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="fast_hang">
                <button type="submit" class="build_submit dark_highlight onlist tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Build instantly with Antimatter.<br> Price : 272 AM" style="float: right; line-height: 18px; margin-right: 13px;">
       <a class="build-faster" >
                            <div class="build-faster-img" alt="Halve time"></div>
                            <span class="build-txt">Instant build.</span>
                            <span class="dm_cost overmark">272 AM</span>
                            <span class="order_dm">Purchase with AM.</span>
       </a>
      </button>
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Firstly, don't use `table`s for layout and try to avoid using `position:absolute` - [**Learn Layout**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Also, please post only the **relevant** pieces of code. Limit it to 10-20 lines of HTML, and 10-20 lines of CSS. See **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Almost no one will look at it, or if they do, the answers could be off with that much code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Overwiev bottom */

.content-box-s {
  margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 222px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
bottom: -140px;
}

.content-box-s:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content-box-s:nth-child(2) {
  left: 222px;
}

.content-box-s:nth-child(3) {
  left: 442px;
}

.content-box-s:hover {
  margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
  width: 222px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content-box-s:hover #inhalt {
bottom: 0;
}

.content-box-s .header {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/b9de2f5b06c823d628d22c4067ee35.gif") no-repeat;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.content-box-s .content {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/bd764e9b39a1a48ad708039fda1bde.gif") repeat-y;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.content-box-s p {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.content-box-s .footer {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/174d5c09f617701fcaf1664a414869.gif") no-repeat;
  height: 21px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

div.content-box-s .header h3 {
  color: #6f9fc8;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 222px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contentbox {
  margin: 0 3px 0 2px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
#buttonz .contentbox .header,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header,
.contentbox .footer,
.contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  background-image: url("../images/Build_tmp/191d6af9367f608bbee2743866c489.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 -1px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header,
.contentbox .header {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-right {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-left {
  background-position: 0 -33px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-right {
  background-position: 100% -66px;
  left: auto;
  right: -2px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .content,
.contentbox .content {
  border-left: 5px double #000;
  border-right: 5px double #000;
  background: #0d1014;
  margin: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer,
.contentbox .footer {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
  height: 21px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 7px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-left {
  background-position: 0 -125px;
  left: -8px;
  right: auto;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  background-position: 100% -150px;
  left: auto;
  right: -8px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-faster-img {
  background-position: -25px -75px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster:hover .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -25px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -75px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content {
  min-height: 46px;
  height: auto!important;
  height: 46px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 177px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:link,
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:visited,
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:active {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-touch #inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction.active {
  background: #171d23;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #171d23), color-stop(100%, #101419));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#171d23', endColorstr='#101419', GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid #171d23;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.queue {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .transport_ecke {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ae6b67d617f5b4a9ad508219ca02b8.png");
  margin: 0 0 -18px 0;
  padding: 1px 5px 2px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  top: -16px;
  width: 35px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 162px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster-img,
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/f67f646a967bc6e4f54dcfcc2c3f2b.png") -25px 0 no-repeat;
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 1px 7px 0 7px;
  width: 25px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .order_dm {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-faster-img {
  background-position: -25px -50px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost,
#inhalt .content-box-s .buy_dm {
  color: #848484;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost .oldPrice {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-style: italic;
}

img.queuePic {
  border: 1px solid #141e26;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a:hover img.queuePic {
  border-color: #e7ae46;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 43px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first div {
  position: relative;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .desc {
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 130px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timer {
  color: #fff;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .ausbau {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .level {
  color: #a26d00;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll {
  padding: 5px 0 0 12px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll .shipAllCountdown,
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip .shipCountdown {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction tr.queue td {
  color: #848484;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .queue_link {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 32px;
}

#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:link,
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:visited,
.no-touch #box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:hover,
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:active {
  background: transparent none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}

#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -moz-opacity: .6;
  -khtml-opacity: .6;
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%
}

table.construction #Countdown,
table.construction #researchCountdown,
table.construction .shipCountdown {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#stationbuilding .construction a,
#stationbuilding .construction a:active {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/0349d693b02c1927643248e4167cf8.gif") no-repeat;
  color: #ff9600;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.no-touch #stationbuilding .construction a:hover,
#stationbuilding .construction a.active {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}

.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a:hover,
#resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active,
#resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link,
#resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active,
.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
#resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ce2e012805bae16d3bc0967600eb58.gif") no-repeat;
  color: #ff9600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}

.dark_highlight {
  background: #181e25 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1030px repeat-x;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2d3743), color-stop(100%, #181e25));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: #28323e #222b34 #232a34 #222b34;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

.dark_highlight:hover {
  background: #2d3743 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1080px repeat-x;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #181e25), color-stop(100%, #2d3743));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: #232b34 #232b34 #29323d #232b34;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
}

#planet1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 679px;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info span {
  color: #27db7d;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info2 {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.planet2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.planet2 .img_img {
  width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
}

.planet2:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
}

.planet2 .img_description {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="inhalt">
  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Buildings</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="idle">
              <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There is no buildings done at the moment. Click here to get to your buildings page." href="../game/game.php?page=buildings">
    You are not building anything at the moment.
   </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>



  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Research</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="construction active">

          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Computer Technology</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="first" rowspan="3">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="cancel_tech">
                <button type="submit" class="del" title="Cancel expansion of Computer Technology To Level (22)">
     <div>
                            <a >
                                <img class="queuePic" width="40" height="40" src="./styles/theme/gow/gebaeude/108.gif" alt="Computer Technology">
                            </a>
       <a>
                                <img src="../game/styles/images/del_build.jpg" height="15" width="15" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
     </button>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="desc ausbau">Improve to Level<span class="level"> (22)</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc">Duration:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc timer">
              <span id="Countdown" class="countdown2" secs="15461"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td colspan="2">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="queuetype" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="fast_tech">
                <button type="submit" class="build_submit dark_highlight onlist tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Build instantly with Antimatter.<br> Price : 858 AM" style="float: right; line-height: 18px; margin-right: 13px;">
       <a class="build-faster" >
                            <div class="build-faster-img" alt="Halve time"></div>
                            <span class="build-txt">Instant build.</span>
                            <span class="dm_cost overmark">858 AM</span>
                            <span class="order_dm">Purchase with AM.</span>
       </a>
      </button>
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>



  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Hangar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="construction active">

          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Solar Satellite</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="first" rowspan="3">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="cancel_hangar">
                <button type="submit" class="del" title="Cancel building. Solar Satellite">
     <div>
                            <a>
                                <img class="queuePic" width="40" height="40" src="./styles/theme/gow/gebaeude/212.gif" alt="Computer Technology">
                            </a>
       <a>
                                <img src="../game/styles/images/del_build.jpg" height="15" width="15" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
     </button>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="desc ausbau">Units to build<span class="level"> (995920)</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc">Duration:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td class="desc timer">
              <span id="Countdown" class="countdown2" secs="4881.9607843137"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="data">
            <td colspan="2">
              <form action="game.php?page=overview" method="post" class="build_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="modo" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="fast_hang">
                <button type="submit" class="build_submit dark_highlight onlist tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Build instantly with Antimatter.<br> Price : 272 AM" style="float: right; line-height: 18px; margin-right: 13px;">
       <a class="build-faster" >
                            <div class="build-faster-img" alt="Halve time"></div>
                            <span class="build-txt">Instant build.</span>
                            <span class="dm_cost overmark">272 AM</span>
                            <span class="order_dm">Purchase with AM.</span>
       </a>
      </button>
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works nice, but what i need to do , to center my divs ? Right now they are in a left side of screen.